# Pop-up does not dismiss

Tags: android, popup, dismiss

I have a `EditText` view,

```
<EditText
android:layout_weight="1"
android:id="@+id/etMiktar"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/miktarHint"
android:focusable="false">
</EditText>
```

And I implemented a pop-up window which opens when the user touches this EditText view. This pop-up window has a button, so when clicked pop-up supposed to be dismissed. Although it gets my clicks, the pop-up does not close.
Here is my pop-up implementation:

```
private void inflatePopUpSiparis(){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
    this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final PopupWindow pwSiparis = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.siparismiktarpopup, null, false),400,550,true);         
    pwSiparis.showAtLocation(this.findViewById(R.id.llMain), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    //pwSiparis.setFocusable(true);
    View myPopUpSiparisView = pwSiparis.getContentView();

    etSiparisMiktar=(EditText)myPopUpSiparisView.findViewById(R.id.etSiparisMiktar);
    etSiparisMiktar.setText(etUrunMiktar.getText().toString());

    btnPopUpSiparisTamam=(Button)myPopUpSiparisView.findViewById(R.id.btnPopUpSiparis);
    btnPopUpSiparisTamam.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pwSiparis.dismiss();
            Log.d("****",etSiparisMiktar.getText().toString().toString());
            etUrunMiktar.setText(etSiparisMiktar.getText().toString());
      }
    });


}
```

}

What could be the problem?

Comment: `//here I get FC` is that comment still relevant?  If so, post a stack trace

Comment: no actually it is totally irrelevant. Not I changed the code, I declared popup window in the method: final PopupWindow pwSiparis. It started to work weirdly, now I need to press the button two times. It gets both clicks but dismiss in the second???

Comment: Probably your dismis function is behind a button or some another class, it would be a better idea to set dismiss function on onClick method to let the app easy finds its function, otherwise it will take some time or errors when tapping on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was; I was using onTouchListener for the EditText. As [dmon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642161/dmon) , stated in the  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10377470/1175195) for the similar problem, onTouchListener responds for both landing and lifting. So when I changed it to onClickListener the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I use following code to start a custom dialog which is similar to PopUp. If you need I can share the layout file as well. `dialog.cancel();` is also similar to dismiss.

```
private void showpopup(int popuptype, String message) {

    //set up dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

    //dialog.setTitle("This is my custom dialog box");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    //there are a lot of settings, for dialog, check them all out!

    //set up text
    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textViewSubject);
    text.setText(message);       

    //set up button
    Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonOK);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("Alert", "Nothing");
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    //now that the dialog is set up, it's time to show it    
    dialog.show();  
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still cannot understand why I am facing with this, because I have also another pop-up that works perfect, but this one I need to press the button twice for dismiis.