# Android View.OnKeyListener: click once, execute twice

Tags: android, view, listener, scrollview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [public boolean onKey() called twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802887/public-boolean-onkey-called-twice)

Here is my code

```
public class TestKeyActivity extends Activity {

private int i=1;
private ScrollView sv;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    sv=(ScrollView) this.findViewById(R.id.read_scrollView);

    sv.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT) {

        Toast.makeText(TestKeyActivity.this, "what is wrong！！！！"+(i++), 2).show();
            return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    }
}
```

I use he Android emulator and Eclipse，I don't know why, but when I click the key once, the code
of toast will execute twice.
Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 12):

I just answered a very similar question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377049/unwilling-edittext-ontouchlistener-function-call/10377470#10377470)). The problem is that you're activating on `KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `KeyEvent.ACTION_UP`. You should only execute your code if `KeyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP`

Comment: yes！its similar but not same.my problem is OnKeyListener ,it will not have KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN and KeyEvent.ACTION_UP this kind of problem.and thank you dmon. you have such score ,cool!

Comment: can i control this with code :if i click the key and in 1 second this key will be locked? is there anyways

Comment: Hmmmm what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi dmon， I try your suggestion。Yes，you are right.It can work. i should switch with KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN and KeyEvent.ACTION_UP  thks